# Не работает "|" в регулярном выражении, почему?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Ввожу имя пользователя в input. По условию имя может быть либо на английском ИЛИ на русском, пишу регулярное выражение вида:

```
let templateFullName = /([a-zA-Z]+)|([а-яА-Я]+)/;
```

Оно должно принять целую строку только русских букв ИЛИ целую строку только английских букв,но не работает, почему?

Comment: Вам следует обозначить начало и конец строки для обоих случаев /^([a-zA-Z]+)$|^([а-яА-Я]+)$/

Comment: Спасибо вам!!!)

Comment: Вы букву `ё` забыли, кстати. Должно быть `/(^[a-zA-Z]+$)|(^[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+$)/`

Comment: точно) они же отдельно находятся) спасибо! подправил)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы была целая строка необходимо указать начало строки и конец, тогда "ИЛИ" заработает

```
(^[a-zA-Z]+$)|(^[а-яёА-ЯЁ]+$)
```

Comment: Не знаю как я косякнул, но такой вариант ранее пробовал - не сработал) сейчас чудо случилось

Comment: Спасибо за наводку!